# Characteristic polynomial of convex combination

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial, rank-1-matrices

Given the following lemma on rank-$1$ matrices which I think I understand

> [image]

How could I deduce the following on the characteristic polynomial of $A_s$? I don't get it just using multilinearity of determinant. The hypothesis of Theorem 1 is just that $A,B \geq 0$

[image]

Comment: Please consider transcribing the screenshot.  Where is the screenshot from?

Comment: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/130935537 Unfortunately, I can't share full article. I don't know if it can consulted online

Comment: Please include the full reference and the DOI link in the question itself

Comment: Note: the statement $\lambda_2 \gt \rho(A)$ doesn't make sense based on what you've told us.  *I suggest taking a different route:* try to prove the equivalent statement $p_s = p_0 + s\cdot (p_1-p_0)$, use $\det\big(C  - tI\big)$ for characteristic polynomial (you can play around with signs later), write $B-A = \mathbf {uv}^T$, work in the ring $\mathbb R[s, t]$ and use the the adjugate form of the of the Matrix Determinant Lemma.

Comment: The reference suppose that the matrix is invertible, which might not be my case @user8675309

Comment: I don't know what your comment *"The reference suppose that the matrix is invertible, which might not be my case"* means.  I will repeat my suggestion of using the *adjugate form* of the Matrix Determinant Lemma and note it makes zero assumptions about invertibility.  That is why it is appropriate for a polynomial ring like $\mathbb R[s, t]$

Comment: another option which is conceptually simple but notationally quite difficult is to send $t\mapsto 0$, and focus on the determinant. Now $\Big(p_0(0) + s\cdot \big(p_1(0)-p_0(0)\big)-p_s(0)\Big) \in\mathbb R[s]$ is a polynomial in $s$ with degree at most $1$ but has two roots (i.e. $s\mapsto 0$ and $s\mapsto 1$) hence is the zero polynomial.  Now observe the same argument holds for each $d-1 \times d-1$ principal minor, the sum of which gives you another coefficient of the characteristic polynomial, and the same argument holds for each $d-2 \times d-2$ principal minor and so on.

Comment: @user8675309 Could you please add a reference of “adjugate formula” ecc?

Comment: ref "The theorem can also be stated in terms of the adjugate matrix of A" near the top of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma